# Trouble using jQuery UI resizeable and draggable together

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm trying to allow dropped elements to be both draggable and resizeable within the parent container.

Here is my CSS:

```
.toolitem {padding:5px 10px;background:#ececec;border:1px solid silver}.labelitem {width:114px;padding:10px 5px;color:#222;background:#fff;border:1px solid silver}
```

Here is my html:

```
<header>
 <ul>
     <li><div id="atool" class="toolitem droppable">A</div></li>
     <li><div id="btool" class="toolitem droppable">B</div></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="clear"></div></header><section id="container"/>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(".toolitem").draggable({
    opacity:1,
    tolerance:'fit',
    helper:'clone'
});
$("#container").droppable({
    accept:'.droppable',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // Check for new or already dropped element
        var dropped = ui.draggable.data("dropped");
        if (dropped == null && dropped != "1") {
            // Create new element only once
            var label = $('<div class="labelitem droppable">[Label]</div>');
            // Set flag as dropped
            label.data("dropped", "1");
            // Make new element draggable within parent
            label.draggable({ containment: 'parent', grid: [2, 2], helper: 'original' });
            // Make new element resizable within parent
            label.resizable({ containment: 'parent' });
            // Append new element to parent
            label.appendTo(this);
        }
    }
});
```

The above code executes well, except the dropped div is not resizeable. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. After googling for an hour, I found I was missing the following include

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

It was needed for resizing div's styles. Everything is now working as expected. But, strange it is never mentioned in jQueryUI documentation or did I miss it.